# Why does Spray app on Heroku fail with "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch"

Tags: heroku, spray

I used Typesafe Config configuration to get environment variable like this:

```
service {
   host = "localhost"
   host = ${?HOST}
   port = 8080
   port = ${?PORT}
     ports {
       tcp = 6969
       ws = 6696
     }
 }
```

And in my `Boot.scala` I wrote:

```
  val host = config.getString("service.host")
  val portHTTP = config.getInt("service.port")
  val rootService = system.actorOf(Props(new RootService()))

  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(rootService, interface = host, port = portHTTP)
```

This is supposed to be just fine! And I saw the `heroku log` info:

```
2014-08-30T17:39:38.867872+00:00 app[web.1]: [spray-blog-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://spray-blog/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:25870
2014-08-30T17:40:37.007696+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

It seems like I have already bound to a specific port: `Bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:25870`, but after 60 seconds Heroku is still saying that I didn't bind to it in time!

I copied and pasted my start script from a Heroku provided sample app: `web: target/start com.mturk.Boot -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf`

I can't figure out what the issue is! So frustrated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Heroku tells you the port you must use.  You can pick up the $PORT environment variable from Heroku in your Boot.scala with an extra line of code

> val myPort = Properties.envOrElse("PORT", "8080").toInt // for
>   Heroku compatibility
>
> IO(Http)(system) ! Http.Bind(rootService, "0.0.0.0", port = myPort)

You might need an extra import of course:

> import util.Properties

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER** Just giving you a hint on how to *potentially* resolve the issue. I apologise if the answer is really of no help.

Could that be that the port you see in the logs is a random one that Spray auto-generated, and Heroku merely checks its own and hence the mismatch manifested in the error? Just guessing.

I'm using the following `build.sbt` so I can work with Typesafe Config:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"
```

No other files are in the project.

I ran sbt with `SBT_OPTS="-Dhttp.port=10876"` to mimic how Heroku passes the configuration to applications - via system properties.

```
➜  typesafe-config  SBT_OPTS="-Dhttp.port=10876" xsbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to typesafe-config (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/typesafe-config/)
> console
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/typesafe-config/}typesafe-config...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

scala> val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
conf: com.typesafe.config.Config = Config(SimpleConfigObject({"awt":{"toolkit":"sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit"},"file":{"encoding":...

scala> conf.getInt("http.port")
res0: Int = 10876
```

Can you try to use `http.port` not `HOST` to check whether or not the environment variable is passed to your application?